# Android studio "Some conflicts were found in the installation area"

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 (Fedora 35 fully updated). It does not show any updates, unless I click on Check updates. Then it shows that Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 is an update. When I ask it to update I get an error window, saying that "Some conflicts were found in the installation area", and the update aborts. Still using 2020.3.1.

Is there any way to solve this? Should I install the thing manually or wait for Studio to tell me there is an update without forcing the Check updates?

Answer (score 0):

Today the Update message appeared automatically (without manual triggering) and the update went smoothly as always (it gave some errors with gradle paths but were solved easily).